# How to update my data sources on visual studio 2012 c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a windows form application c# and I put spaces inside my database title fields which meant I had to go back and put an '_' whereever there was a space, eg "First_Name".

I done this but when I click refresh in the data source window in Visual studio it doesnt update the data set for some reason?

How do I update the data sets to have the titles include underscores in replace of the spaces?

Thanks

Comment: don't use underscores or spaces in table or column names. Everytime you do, a cute puppy dies.

Comment: Awhh, poor puppies :(

Comment: Is there a way to ammend my mistake and update my datasource?

Answer (score 0):

enable Data migration using the package manager console (PMC)
Check this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-entity-framework-scaffolding-and-migrations)

TO Enable Data migration in MVC (To be applied if the data model has been changed after it was created)

1.open **PMC** 
2. Type Command 
**Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName YOURDBContext** 
3. Then 
**Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase** 
4. At last **Update-Database -Verbose**

Comment: Is there an easier to do this like on visual studio or should I just start again?

Comment: it will update all the changes you have made.. follow the link for more details.

Comment: I don't understand what I have to do sorry because the link you sent me is really long and I am not doing a web application, it's a windowsformapplication.

Comment: Scroll down to Task 3 . it is for MVC but it might still work with windows forms application. my bad i thought it was a MVC application.

Comment: So there's no other way to update the data source on visual studio? :(